# Laravel groupBy a JSON column's key

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with Laravel 9 and PHP 8.1, I have two models, a `Product` and `ProductOption`. Product options are joined to Products and contain an optional, nullable `json` field called `extra` where additional custom data about a product option may be stored.

I have created a bunch of product options where the `extra` field contains a "region" and "regions", for example:

```json
{
    "region": "us",
    "regions": [
        "us"
    ]
}
```

When performing my query to get all products, I'd like to group the joined options to my `Product` by the region, so it might end up looking something like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  options: [
    us: [
      {
        id: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2
      }
    ],
    eur: [
      {
        id: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

This is my current query:

```php
$product = $request->input('product');
$type = $request->input('type');

$products = Product::where('slug', $product)
->where('is_enabled', true)
->with(['options' => function ($query) use ($type) {
    $query->where('is_enabled', true)
          ->whereNotNull('extra')
          ->whereJsonLength('extra->regions', 1)
          ->where('slug', 'like', "%$type%")
          ->select('extra->region as region');
}])->get();
```

I was thinking I could do something like `groupBy('extra->region')` but this throws an error.

#### UPDATE

I've tried added a `select()` statement statement to attempt to pull out the "region" field from my JSON `extra` column. This returns the following error:

> The attribute [product_id] either does not exist or was not retrieved for model [App\Models\ProductOption].

Comment: Did you try a select('column->property as field') and then the groupBy by this field?

Comment: Would be useful if you disclose the error to us :). Normally I cast my JSON columns to arrays in the model, which makes it easier I find. Can you add the error message?

Comment: @Aless55 I've updated my original post with my findings from this. It does throw an error. "extra" is my column name, and it's JSON, inside this is a `region` key.

Comment: @geertjanknapen Updated original post with my findings.

Comment: I think you might better achieve what you want with the Collection's groupBy method. If you want to group by in the SQL query, you could try with raw expressions. For example `groupByRaw("JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT('extra', '$.\"region\"'))")` or `groupByRaw("\"extra\"->>'region'")` in postgres.

Comment: I think casting the column to an array would enable you to do what you want, as described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) here.

Comment: @IGP Thanks for your reply. I tried this and it throws an error: `Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'snapisms_db.product_options.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: Try adding the same stuff you put in your group by in the select clause.